# Two nodemcu's unable to communicate with raspberry pi using mqtt

Tags: raspberry-pi, mqtt, nodemcu

Raspberry pi is acts as local host i'm trying to send data to raspbberry pi using mqtt with node mcu with two different topics. 
eg:
if x>10 then i send 1 otherwise 0

same logic i have used in both node mcu.

if im communicate with only one nodemcu it getting good response but if i connect with both nodemcu's then sometimes not getting value in raspberry pi console.

Answer (score 0):

This often depends on both the client and the broker used, and your configuration of each. The fact that two have problems where one does not suggests a **client ID collision**: every MQTT client device must have a different client ID. If a broker receives subscriptions from two clients with the same ID, the broker may disconnect one, usually the first. If each client is configured to reconnect, this can cause an endless series of disconnects for both, each of them connected half the time.

Any broker that does not disconnect duplicate clients could still fail to deliver to one, because it uses the client IDs to track which clients a message has been delivered to. The first client that pings for messages on its subscriptions will receive the latest message, and any later ones will miss that message because the message is already marked as delivered to that client ID.

Most clients avoid these problems with **random IDs**, yet let the developer set one manually. Does your identical logic set a client ID? You can verify what is actually set on each device through the **broker's logs**.